# Environment for greyed-out (or otherwise color) text

Tags: environments

Sorry for being as clueless as the last times I asked but also having done no research because I have to finish this overhead presentation for tomorrow...

Is there a good way to create an environment which makes all text inside it colored in a certain color?

I have tried:

```
\newenvironment{rrpptt}{\textcolor{gray}}{\textcolor{black}}
```

But this doesn't yield what I want... It gives a compile error and just puts the word "rrpptt" inside the text. What am I doing wrong?

Of course I do have the color package loaded. I also have the beamer documentclass - is that a problem?

Oh, and I don't care about \textcolor being lowlevel and stuff - I don't have footnotes and sudden page changes, so I would be content with the way \textcolor normally works, if it would do so.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `\textcolor` macro takes a second argument, which is the text to be coloured. The `\color` macro changes the colour until the end of the current group or environment. So I think you need something like this.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
\newenvironment{redtext}{\color{red}}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
Here is some black text.
\begin{redtext}
And here is some red text.
\end{redtext}
Here is more black text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @darij (and @Ian) You could even omit the \color{black} at end of the definition because the environment itself is a group … It is also recommended to use xcolor instead of color.

Maybe you would like to add `\ignorespacesafterend` at end of the definition to prevent unwished spaces.

Comment: @Tobi --- you are right, putting `\black` there was pointless. I didn't know about `\ignorespacesafterend`, so thanks for a useful tip.

Comment: How do we get this working for grey text (or somehow faded). I tried colors "gray", but it says that is undefined (though I can see "gray" in the documentation).

Comment: @Jeff --- Use `xcolor` rather than `color`. This has predefined colours `gray`, `lightgray` and `darkgray`. Otherwise, you can define your own by doing something like `\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.75}`.