# Color part of text and captions

Tags: color, captions, environments

is it possible to color in red **part** of a text and/or of a caption (let's say, just some words)?

I tried to create the environment:

```
\newenvironment{redtext}{\color{red}}{\ignorespacesafterend}
```

following [this reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/environment-for-greyed-out-or-otherwise-color-text). However, it cannot be used for captions.

Thank you.

Comment: Which class file are you used `minimal` or `article` and could you please post MWE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For captions you can use the interface provided by the »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« package. Have a look at this approach derived from Section 4 of the package manual.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareCaptionFont{red}{\color{red!50!black}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{green}{\color{green!50!black}}
\captionsetup{
  labelfont={bf,red},
  textfont={green}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \rule{8cm}{4.5cm}
    \caption{Dummy figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It should be no big deal to apply that in your document.

---

[image]

---

**Update**

For only parts of the caption you can use the `\textcolor` command. It's suggestive to define a new command in this case.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\alert}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \rule{8cm}{4.5cm}
    \caption{This is a \alert{Dummy figure}}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: What if I have to color just part of a caption (let's say, some words)? I think the method you are proposing is coloring the whole caption.

Comment: @Eleanore: Then you can simply use `\textcolor{red}{Colored text}` as described in Section 2.6 of the »[xcolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)« manual. Somehow I must have misinterpreted your question.